# Which should I use for iOS development, a C library the Java version?

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, java-native-interface

I am working on an iPhone project and want to use an open source library which I found in both java and C. Currently I am working on iPhone only, but later I plan to port to other platforms too. It's a client-server app, where server is already java-based.

What I want to do is to design iPhone UI in objective-c which communicates with java-based or C-based client library.

As far as I know, a Java-based library will remain the best option for me because it is cross-platform, but what about Objective-c and Java communication. Is it possible using JNI, and will it take more time to develop than C, and what abt software efficiency?? Which should I choose, C or java-based library, bearing in mind fast development lifecycle?

Through Googling, I learned that Java and Objecive-c communication is possible using a "Java bridge", but I read another post, which said that Apple has restricted the use of "java bridge" in Mac OS X 10.4 and later...

Given that information, which version of the library should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use C.

Java does not run on iOS. You would need to communicate with a web server to execute Java code.

However, for your web service, I would recommend using Java, since your server already runs Java. To communicate with the service from the app, define some endpoints and then make HTTP request from your app to the server.

Comment: you mean i should write iOS app which communicates with web server, and the web server in turn should communicate with Java-based server... So that's not better solution for me, as my app is sort of real-time,,, i want my app to respond in real time... so using C will be the best option for me... Thank you so much,,, Cheers

Comment: Your app can communicate with a Java server directly, you just can't run Java *on* the iPhone itself. Just make http requests to "somePage.jsp".

Comment: If you have to talk over the web at all, your app is not "real time".  Even if all your code is running locally, it will not be "real time" since the iOS kernel does not guarantee timing of anything...  If you just mean "run as quickly as possible" then running locally with C libraries would be fine.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner That is true, but I guess "real-time" is impossible to achieve anywhere, because there is always limitations imposed by hardware and software. I would say that "realtime" here means "as close to realtime as possible".

Comment: Real-time is possible, as there are many real-time systems around.  All real-time means is that you know the maximum possible time some operation can take.

Answer (score 3):

If your code need to run on the iPhone you can not use Java. There is no jvm (for a non jailbroken device).